# Stylelint 14 fix on save not working on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, eslint, stylelint

When I was using stylelint 13, it was working fine, but for some reason after I upgraded to version 14, the fix on save function didn't work, but stylelint has correctly marked the error

Following is my settings:

stylelint.config.cjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWPIA.png)

```
// setting.json

  {
    "files.associations": {
       "*.vue": "vue"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true,
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
      "javascript",
      "javascriptreact",
      "typescript",
      "typescriptreact"
    ],
    "editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation": true,
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "strings": true
    },
    "css.validate": false,
    "less.validate": false,
    "scss.validate": false,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "stylelint.snippet": [
      "css",
      "less",
      "postcss",
      "scss"
    ],
    "stylelint.validate": [
      "css",
      "less",
      "postcss",
      "scss",
      "html",
      "javascript",
      "vue-html",
      "vue-postcss",
      "sass",
      "markdown",
      "vue",
    ],
    "[vue]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
    },
     "[javascript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[html]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
  }
```

It should automatically format after I save it.